# Find the right COM to setup Winlink

Tags: packet, linux

I managed to successfully install Winlink on my Ubuntu operating system  but it is not completely functional yet. I don't know which COM my computer is set up to use, and there are a lot of them available.

That's my question though, how to quickly find the right COM without going through each and every one individually. Thank you very much, and I look forward to hearing from you.

[image: Winlink]

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  Is Winlink running natively?  In WINE?  In a VM?  What type of serial port is it plugged into? (USB or RS-232)

Comment: Winlink is running in Wine. It's got two 3.5 mm cables going from the TNC to the mic and earphones. And there is a data connection that fits into the back of the radio. I own a FT-7900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running under WINE, you can make the port whatever you want.  You need to know the Linux device name (like /dev/ttys0 or /dev/ttyUSB or whatever) the TNC is plugged into on the computer.  Then all you do is set up a symlink in ~/.wine/dosdevices that "connects" the two.  If you look in that directory, you can see the default devices already set up.  If you don't know how to set up a symlink, look for help on the ln command.

Comment: In Wine 2.0 or newer, putting symlinks for com ports in `~/.wine/dosdevices` isn't very effective (they're overwritten on startup). Instead, one should add a registry entry in `HKLM\Software\Wine\Ports`, which will make it actually stick.

Comment: @hobbs-KC2G You should submit that as your own answer.

Comment: @rclocher3 when I get a chance. At work now, no time to do a proper job :)

Comment: A link to support Hobbs' answer: https://wiki.winehq.org/index.php?title=Wine_User%27s_Guide&oldid=2519#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports